# Merge JSON arrays based on arbitrary keys to arrays

Tags: json, merge, command-line-interface, jq, jtc

Using `jq` or `jtc`, I'd like to take a list of json files as inputs and generate a single json file based on the keys to the arrays found in each input file. Example:

1st file:

```json
{
  "key1": [
    "key1-out1"
  ]
}
```

2nd file:

```json
{
  "key1": [
    "key1-out2"
  ]
}
```

3rd file:

```json
{
  "key2": [
    "key2-out1"
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
  "key1": [
    "key1-out1"
    "key1-out2"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "key2-out1"
  ]
}
```

I encountered [this almost perfectly good answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433687/135796) but I can't use it directly because I don't know what keys I will get in each input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case any of the files has more than one key:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; 
        reduce ($in|keys_unsorted)[] as $k (.;
         .[$k] += $in[$k]))'  file1 file2 file3 # ...
```

You might want to tweak this so it doesn't fail if the value associated with a key is unexpectedly not an array.

And if you use gojq (the Go implementation of jq), you would use `keys` rather than `keys_unsorted`.